# Error al descargar paquete en python

Tags: python, pip

he estado intentado por estos ultimos dias descargar la libreria **vidstream**, tal libreria cuenta con 3 dependencias:

Dependecias

> pyaudio, opencv-python ,pyautogui

Dichas dependencias fueron instaladas usando **pip**, pero al descargar la libreria **pyaudio** me dio un problema esto ha sido lo que he hecho

(Comando en el CMD)

```
pip install pyaudio
```

(error)

> Collecting pyaudio   Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio   Building wheel for
> pyaudio (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit
> status 1:    command:
> 'c:\users\0.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u
> -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yjf3p7pm\pyaudio_10680ee5de7143faa1fe1976024ce885\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yjf3p7pm\pyaudio_10680ee5de7143faa1fe1976024ce885\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ehucpk2p'
> cwd: C:\Users\0.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yjf3p7pm\pyaudio_10680ee5de7143faa1fe1976024ce885
> Complete output (9 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win32-3.8
> copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8   running build_ext
> building '_portaudio' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is
> required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio

Tambien he probado instalar de una **vidstream** usando `pip install vidstream` y me da el mismo error.

Agradecería de mucho su ayuda espero tambien ayudar a alguien con mi pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta es la siguiente:

"Para instalar ciertos **paquetes con requisitos externos** como en esta caso **Visual Studio**, podemos también hacerlo usando la extensión **.whl**"

**Estos son los pasos:**

Ingresar a sitio web de [Unofficial-PythonLibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), y buscar la libreria que necesitamos **pyaudio**. Luego de hacer eso descargue las versión `PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`.(la versión puede variar segun la versión de python)

Posteriormente **abrí el cmd como administrador**, y puse el siguiente comando: `py -m pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`

Y para comprobar la información descargada, abri el IDLE y escribí el siguiente comando: **import pyaudio**

**Muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron**

Answer (score 2):

Como menciona el error, necesitas descargar e instalar [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Comment: Entonces lo unico que tengo que hacer es instalarlo y ya, no hay una configuración por aparte ?, y tambien que podre usar el modulo en pycharm ?

Comment: Sí, instálalo, y por lo menos ese error debería quedar solucionado.

Comment: Hola, lo he estado intentando instarlo pero me quedo en una parte donde me pide que eliga lo que tengo que descargar, me podrías ayudar en esa parte, ya que no vi ningun nombre python ahí y si instalo todo mi quedo sin almacenamiento en mi laptop, agradecería tu ayuda : )